# In the home? Is it correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this phrase mean? Is it correct?
I encountered it while browsing the Internet.

Please take a look at the screenshot below.

Source: https://strategiesforparents.com/about/

[image]

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? Am I being punished for asking questions? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine.

In text, the prepostional phrase "at home" is more common, but here it is unremarkable.

The reason why "In the home" has a prepostion, and the others don't seems likely to be because in website menus  "Home" means "Link to the homepage of the website". So "In the home" avoids that ambiguity.  It means "Menu of strategies for parents in the home context and environment".